# Wireless conection stops working after app. 30min on RTL8723BE

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo, realtek-wireless

Just at the beginning: I'm a totally noob with Ubuntu. I got it about 1h ago so i don't know anything basically. Also my English is not the best so i hope you'll overlook it gentelly ;)

So here is my problem:

Every time, i start my Laptop, it connets with my Wlan Rooter properly. However, about half an hour later, the connection collapses and it only shows the Wlans searching annimation. But it doesn't find any connection to my Wlan at all. I tried turing the WLAN router as well as the Wlan antenna of my laptop off and back on again....the problem does not get fixed.

Maybe you'll need some information to help me, here is everything i can guess about. If you need more details, you will have to give me detailed instructions on how to get them.

I'm using

-the latest Ubuntu 14.04.2

-Lenovo Flex 14 (laptop)

-Alice Wlan Router

I did not install any programs expect Skype for Linux.

Every time I try to deactivate the wifi connection to re-enable it later on, it give me a little window (32)

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723] 
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736] 
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Try opening a terminal (press control+alt+T simultaneously), and type the command "sudo service network-manager restart" without the quotes. This should restart the networking of your computer. Does it reconnect properly?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work...the is no connection build up automatically and if i try it manual, it doesn't connect either.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Here is the result: "02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
"

Comment: Please do not add this kind of information in comments [edit] your question instead. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a better wireless driver for this chip. Run these commands in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

And reboot.

Comment: Thanks, i did update the drivers and will respond weather it worked or not. Thank u very much!

Comment: If it works do not forget to accept the answer by clicking "bird" at the left.

Comment: Worked :D Thank u again very much for ur quick and working soloution. And also for the simple way of explaining what i have to do;)